# How to Bind Grid with Properties in Code behind?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, c#-4.0

I have a grid in a XAML file and I want to generate its `RowDefinition` dynamically. To do that I create a `List<RowDefinition>` in which I add 3-4 `RowDefinition`s. Now I have to bind this property to the grid in the XAML file. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you post the xaml and code you have at the moment. It is not clear as to why you are trying to bind to RowDefinitions which is generally concerned about layout and not data.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to host dynamic content (varying number of items), the `Grid` control might not be your best option. Try using an `ItemsControl` (which can be templated to look however you want) and bind your actual data against the ItemsSource property. If you post some more information about what kind of content you are looking to display I can give you an example of how to do it with an ItemsControl.